# How to scroll the page left to right in selenium for different div tags

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape all the apps url from the target page:- https://play.google.com/store/apps?device= using the below code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

items = ['phone','tablet','tv','chromebook','watch','car']
target_url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps?device="

all_apps = []
for cat in tqdm(items):
    driver.get(target_url+cat)
    time.sleep(2)
    
    new_height = 0
    last_height = 0
    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(4)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")


        # break condition
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
        
    for i in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href,'/store/apps/details')]"):
        all_apps.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

The above code scrolls the page upside down and gives me the URLs of all the apps available on the page. However,

[image: The side slider can't be clicked.]

I tried to click the element using the below code but getting error:

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//i[contains(text(),'chevron_right')]").click()

error:-

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.77)
```

I tried using the below code:-

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='bewvKb']") #any icon, may be that whatsapp icon here
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
hover.perform()

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//i[text()='chevron_right']")
element.click()
```

There is no option to click on the highlighted button as shown in the image. Can anyone help me with this like how to scroll the page sideways so that all the contents can be scraped from the page?

Comment: This is the element `<i class="google-material-icons B1yxdb" aria-hidden="true">chevron_right</i>` Try coding to click it and it would work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already tried that, and forgot to mention it in the answer. It's giving an error:  ElementNotInteractableException.

Comment: @LalitJoshi, what is your usecase to get the urls of  `popular apps` and `Editor's choice apps` with given search ex :- phone?

Comment: @KunduK I need to scrape all the apps mentioned on that particular to further scrape their release date and update date. I just need to make sure that I am scraping all the apps URL.

Comment: all the apps under `popular apps` and `Editor's choice apps` right?

Comment: No actually all the apps present under this URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, that right arrow icon appears only when you hover upon any of the icon which is on the line. So first hover any of the icon, so that right arrow would appear and then issue the click, mostly like this

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#yDmH0d > c-wiz.SSPGKf.glB9Ve > div > div > div.N4FjMb.Z97G4e > c-wiz > div > c-wiz > c-wiz:nth-child(1) > c-wiz > section > div > div > div > div > div > div.aoJE7e.b0ZfVe > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > a > div.TjRVLb > img") #any icon, may be that whatsapp icon here
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
hover.perform()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[text()='chevron_right']")
element.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand but using this I can only do it for the first row only not for others. Also, I tried using the code you shared but to no avail. I have eited the main code.